# How to use default constructor while using composition? in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-c++, constructor, default-constructor

i keep getting when i declare Game object in the main : // C2512: no appropriate default constructor available , I am using visual studio , on other compilers that error doesn't always appear .

I tried to change the way to define and initialize but It keep giving me the same error, something like this was in a question in an exam is to have default parameterized constructor and one of the parameters was another class object in composition, but i do this in the code it gives me the error above

so how to use default constructor while using composition ???

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
//#include "Game.h"
//#include "Screen.h"
using namespace std;


class Screen
{
private:
    int resolution;
    int brightness;
    string color;
public:
    Screen(int br = 20, int rl = 10, string colr = "green");
};

Screen::Screen(int br, int rl, string colr) :resolution(rl), brightness(br), color(colr)  {}



class Game {
protected:
    string name;
    Screen screen1;
public:
    Game(Screen& ok, string nam = "minecraft");
};


Game::Game(Screen& ok, string nam) : screen1(ok), name(nam)
{ }



int main()
{
    //Screen screen1;
    Game gg;




    return 0;
}

//screen1 = ok;
```

Comment: Adding `Screen() = default;` to your class definition?

Comment: is ther eother way ?

Comment: Sure: `Screen() {}` would do as well. Or passing the required constructor parameters, when you create the `Screen` instance.

Comment: If you don't have a default constructor, you can't call the default constructor, since does not exist.  Have you tried calling the available constructor in `main` for the `gg` object?

Comment: You're supposed to pass the `Screen` instance when you create `gg`.

Comment: but the `Screen`  have a default constructor ,  shouldn't it be enough to be called and complete the default construction for the `Game` class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constractur `Game(Screen& ok, string nam = "minecraft");` needs to get a reference to `Screen` object.

And when you create `Game` object like this:
`Game gg;`

there's no reference to `Screen` object.

A good example of a constactur call would be:

```
Screen s;
Game gg(s);
```

Other tip is the to put the implementation on other file or where you declare it.
so

`Screen::Screen(int br, int rl, string colr) :resolution(rl), brightness(br), color(colr)  {}`

and `Screen(int br = 20, int rl = 10, string colr = "green");`
would be:

```
Screen(int br = 20, int rl = 10, string colr = "green") 
    :resolution(rl), brightness(br), color(colr)  {}
```

Comment: the first solution did work , but doesn't that change that its default ? 


about the tip , the code was between header and .cpp files , the Dr told us that putting the `:resolution(rl), brightness(br), color(colr)  ` 
should be in the .cpp file not header , is that true ?

Comment: Yes, generally the code goes to the `.cpp` files and the declerations goes to the headers files (`.hpp`). But, if you use only headers files (Like in the case of **Templated classes**) you will only use header files. Also, why did the first solution didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

```
    Game(string nam = "minecraft") : screen1(Screen()), name(nam) {}
```

screen1(Screen()) creates a Screen object with default arguments and assigned to screen1.

The whole program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
//#include "Game.h"
//#include "Screen.h"
using namespace std;


class Screen
{
private:
    int resolution;
    int brightness;
    string color;
public:
    Screen(int br = 20, int rl = 10, string colr = "green"):resolution(rl), brightness(br), color(colr)  {}
};


class Game {

public:
    Game(string nam = "minecraft") : screen1(Screen()), name(nam) {}

protected:

    Screen screen1;
    string name;
};


int main()
{
    //Screen screen1;
    Game gg;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it works for me... I pasted the whole program.

Comment: it worked !! , is there a way to send any parameters to it ? from the main 

also how can I split 
`   Game(string nam = "minecraft") : screen1(Screen()), name(nam) {}`
into header and .cpp files

Comment: then change to     Game(Screen s =Screen(), string nam = "minecraft") : screen1(s), name(nam) {}. You can leave the constructor definition in the header.